# Questions on metalogic and consistency

Tags: logic, metalogic

We know from Godel's theorems that interesting logics can not prove their own consistency, so whenever we want to prove the consistency of such a logic $L$, we need to take a step back, place this logic inside a metalogic $M$ and do the proof there. Which is, although not totally surprising, quite disappointing. What I want to understand is the relationship between the logics $L$ and $M$. So here are some questions about that:

1. What would be a minimal metalogic which can prove consistency of PA?
2. What would be a minimal metalogic which can prove consistency of ZF(C)?
3. What would be a minimal metalogic which can prove Godel's theorems?

**Update**: It turns out that my questions are not well-posed, since 'minimal' does not mean anything unless we define what are acceptable metalogics and how to compare them. Some useful ideas extracted from the comments: Ordinal Analysis (for measuring and comparing strength of various logics) and Reverse Mathematics (for detailed analysis of the role of various axioms in arithmetic), but also Proof Theory in general. Thank you all for contributing.

Comment: Your reading of [Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorems](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) is not exact: the issue is not how to prove *consistency* of "logics" (we prove it with "standard" mathematical techniques) but about proving consistency of (formal) arithmetic and analysis.

Comment: The issue about consistency proofs of arithmetic and analysis was raised in the context of [Hilbert’s Program](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hilbert-program/). A successful meta-logic (obviously) proof od consistency of arithmetic was developed by [G.Gentzen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentzen%27s_consistency_proof) in 1936.

Comment: Regarding the meta-mathematics for Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorems you can see [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307080/how-can-you-formalize-the-metamathematics-conventionally-used-to-state-godel-s-t).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, I know Godel's theorems are not exactly about that, I mentioned this only because they are so linked to consistency results. But my question is more about minimal metalogics needed for proving meta-theorems. For example, if a proof for the consistency of PA needs the full strength of ZFC, I will be more suspicious of PA consistency, because I am suspicious of AC.

Comment: No, the consistency proof of $\mathsf {PA}$ does not need the full strength of $\mathsf {ZFC}$ but needs "something less and something more" than $\mathsf {PA}$ itself: "the base theory of [Gentzen's consistency proof] is *primitive recursive arithmetic* with the additional principle of quantifier-free transfinite induction up to the ordinal $ε_0$"

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA You actually touched on what I'm looking for with |something less and something more". My idea is that if we find different consistency proofs like this (to make up even a hierarchy of metalogics) we could (maybe?) anchor arithmetic (or ZFC) into a metalogic (or chain thereof) where the "something less" takes away axioms that seem counter-intuitive and the "something more" adds axioms which, even though stronger, seem more acceptable for our intuition.

Comment: Maybe... but on what ground we may assert that induction up to $\epsilon_0$ is "moro palatable" than usual induction? even if applied to a "restricted" layer of formulas. Having said that, there is a dedicated discipline, called [Ordinal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_analysis).

Comment: Building off of Mauro's comments I think there are two key points to be made: first of all, the principles arising in ordinal analysis quickly become very complicated, so the hope that they'd be more palatable is (in my opinion) dashed early on. Second of all, the current state-of-the-art of ordinal analysis is somewhere around $\Pi^1_2$-$\mathsf{CA}_0$, a theory which - while vastly stronger than $\mathsf{PA}$ - is vastly vastly *vastly* weaker than $\mathsf{ZFC}$. See the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144041/proof-theoretic-ordinal-of-zfc-or-consistent-zfc-extensions).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for the reference, I was not aware of ordinal analysis.

Comment: @NoahSchweber This is all very interesting content which helps me understand the context a bit better.It seems to me that assigning ordinals is an attempt to assess the exact strength of different logics, whereas I would be satisfied with a lot less than that, namely just making the metalogic a lot more explicit for meta-theorems. I don't know if there is a discipline that studies this rigorously.

Comment: @CristianGratie So in general it actually takes very little to get the metatheorems. E.g. Godel's incompleteness theorems are provable in much less than even $\mathsf{PA}$, while the completeness theorem - depending on how it's actually phrased - is provable "around" the level of $\mathsf{PA}$ itself. Proof theory and reverse mathematics both tackle these sorts of issues. That said, you may be interested in Visser's (truly delightful) paper [**Oracle bites theory**](https://dspace.library.uu.nl/handle/1874/394373), which studies a very mild metatheorem in an absurdly weak system.

Comment: The "minimal metalogic" to prove Con(PA) is just the theory with a single axiom Con(PA). If you don't define what you want from your "metalogic" there is not much more to be said.